# Recreate SID on Google Cloud VM

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, sysprep

I have two virtual machines running in google cloud. They both run MS Server 2012.

It appears that the person who created them used a clone as the machine SID's are the same. This is now causing a problem for things such as WebRoot AV which identify the machines using the SID.

In AWS this is resolved by using the AWS sysprep tool, how can I get solve this s the Google environment?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep tool is a built-in tool that comes with windows itself. So i would suggest you run sysprep by following this [guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2014/05/how-to-sysprep-sysprep-is-a-great-and-powerful-tool-and-easy-too-if-you-know-how-step-by-step/). Note that this wipe out anything installed on your VM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I realise that sysprep is a windows tool, its just that AWS gives you an amazon front end to ensure you keep connectivity to the machine post sysprep. The last thing i need is to lose access to the box due to first boot config screen. I guess just an unattend xml would be the answer?